# delphi, react on copy action or execute paste

Tags: delphi, delphi-2005

How to execute an action in my app always when user click ctrl+v (I want to assign a new alue to clipboard), or how to paste something in active window, when user clicks global hotkey in my app?

Answer (score 1):

When something is pasted the control will receive the [WM_PASTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. So you can intercept this Message.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way (without knowing what else is on your main form) is to add to your main menu items called Copy / Paste - make the shortcuts Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V. Implement routines in response to these menu items click events (or use actions) and your code will get called...